# How to set limit for selecting images using intent

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

Here i shared the my code. Can anyone help?

```
var intent = Intent()
intent.type = "image/*"
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true)
intent.action = Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_MULTIPLE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't look like it's possible when using an intent. Even if we could set that option in the intent, the application which the user chooses will have to support it, which simply cannot be guaranteed.
The easy way to ensure this behaviour will be to use an image picker library which can enforce this behaviour - [Fishbun](https://github.com/sangcomz/FishBun) for example can do this:

```
FishBun.with(WithActivityActivity.this)
        .setImageAdapter(new GlideAdapter())
        .setMaxCount(5)
        .setMinCount(3)
        .startAlbum();
```

Detailed usage instructions can be found in its [README file](https://github.com/sangcomz/FishBun/blob/develop/README.md).

Disclaimer : I'm in no way associated with this library. I suggested it because it looks like its been updated recently and is quite popular.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this 3rd party library.

https://github.com/sangcomz/FishBun?utm_source=android-arsenal.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=2785

Otherwise us the below repo too

https://github.com/darsh2/MultipleImageSelect

Comment: can i get kotlin library

Comment: why you are asking Kotlin Library?. By using these alone you will be done your function.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a limit of your image selection using intent in onActivityResult() like this

```
if(data.getClipData().getItemCount()==15){
     Toast.makeText(context,"You can select maximum 15 images",1).show();                 
}
else //allow selection
```

Comment: Bad idea, the Toast comes out only after the selection is closed meaning you have to go back and select again. It was OK if it would disallow more selection as you are selecting and pop up the Toast, otherwise, it's very unpractical.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for answer in the future, Check [this Library](https://github.com/sjd753/MultipleImageSelect) out